# How can I call a variable from inside a function in another file in Python3 to the currrent file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a `Flask` app with 2 files- `app.py` and `send.py`. After running the operations in `app.py`, it runs `send.py`. `send.py` needs a variable from inside a function `proceed()` in `app.py`. This variable is obtained by getting data from a form (with `requests`). This can be done only in `app.py`. This variable is compulsory for `send.py` to work.

I tried-
`import app`, and did `a = app.email` but used to get an `AttributeError`.

If I do `from app import proceed`, I get an error that `Flask` has no `email`.

Comment: Hello glichty. It would be easier for us to help you , if you displayed the content of your two files.

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot, app.py gets form data and send.py sends email to the email adress obtained in app.py

Comment: You need to show your code. The function that is called in `send.py` should probably take `email` as a parameter

Comment: @IainShelvington it assigns a variable to it.